# EIRP for JWST HGA

Tags: digital-communications, snr, signal-power

I am attempting to compute the EIRP for transmissions from the James Webb Space Telescope using the high-gain antenna.  I found the following reference...

https://www.ioag.org/Public%20Documents/2019-02-22_LEO26SG_Report_Final.pdf

...from which I obtained the following data (Table D-18):

Center frequency: 25900 MHz

Transmit power in 26 GHz band (W and dBW): 55 W = 17.4 dBW

Onboard antenna (size, gain) Parabolic reflector: 0.6 m

Gain: 42.3 dBic

EIRP (dBW): 7.7 dBm

Clearly there is at least a typo here, as the units for EIRP are inconsistent.  But my own calculations using the other numbers don't agree with 7.7 dBW or 7.7 dBm.  If we assume that the 0.6m refers to the reflector diameter, then the antenna gain is
$$
G = \frac{7A}{\lambda^2} = 1.44 \times 10^4 = 41.6 \text{ dB}.
$$

Therefore, the EIRP should be
$$
\mathrm{EIRP} = 17.4 + 41.6 = 59.0 \text{ dBW}.
$$

Am I possibly making a wrong assumption about the data I have obtained?  Is there a better public reference on the details of the JWST communications systems?  Thanks!

Comment: This has to be a mistake. Despite the inconsistent dB reference, the value of 7.7 dBm is VERY small, since this is referenced to a milli-Watt. It's possible that there are some major losses that they are accounting for but not explicitly stating, but I don't see that being likely.

Comment: "*EIRP (dBW): 7.7 dBm*"  It's either EIRP in dBW or in dBm, but certainly not in both at the same time :)